# DateTime algorithm suggestion

Tags: c#, datetime

My requirement is to calculate a date based on another date.
The general rules needed for calculation are:

1. If input date occurs beetwen April 1st and September 30th (any year), the calculated result should be equal to December 31th of the input year
2. If input date occur between October 1st and March 31th, then the calculated result should be equal to "next" June 30th.

As per those requirements I have this code:

```
DateTime tmpDate = new DateTime( 2000, inputDate.Month, inputDate.Day );
DateTime aprilDate = new DateTime( 2000, 4, 1 );
DateTime septemberDate = new DateTime( 2000, 9, 30 );
DateTime endofYearDate = new DateTime( 2000, 12, 31 );
DateTime resultDate = DateTime.MaxValue;

if ( tmpDate >= aprilDate && tmpDate <= septemberDate ) {
    resultDate = new DateTime( inputDate.Year, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59 );
}
else {
    if ( tmpDate > septemberDate && tmpDate <= endofYearDate ) {
        resultDate = new DateTime( inputDate.Year, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59 );
    }
    else {
        resultDate = new DateTime( inputDate.Year + 1, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59 );
    }
}
```

However I think that this code it's a little bit messy. How can I write it in a better way?

Comment: Wouldn't be better in [CodeReview.SE] at least?

Comment: Well, did'nt know about the existence of that site. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks far two complex:

```
if ( inputDate.Month > 3 && inputDate.Month < 10 ) {
    resultDate = new DateTime( inputDate.Year, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59 );
}
else if (inputDate.Month > 9 ) {
    //June, per spec rather than OPs code
    resultDate = new DateTime( inputDate.Year + 1, 6, 30, 23, 59, 59 ); 
} else {
    //Ditto
    resultDate = new DateTime( inputDate.Year, 6, 30, 23, 59, 59 );
}
```

However, the presence of the times on these values does concern me. If you're going to be using these values as the end points for particular periods, I'd recommend instead computing the following July or January 1st and then using `<` comparisons rather than `<=`. You're far less likely to make mistakes such as excluding events that happen *within* the last second of the period.

Comment: well, you're right in regard to times. I have simplified the question for the sake of simplicity. In regard to the code you posted, is'nt that exactly as mine?

Comment: @Lorenzo - no, I'm not constructing a whole load of extra `DateTime` values in the year 2000 just for the sake of comparing `DateTime`s - I'm just comparing the input month values.

Comment: Oh right thank you. Do you think this code can be reviewed to use Timespan's instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime delayedInputDate = inputDate.AddMonths(3);

if (delayedInputDate.Month < 7)
    resultDate = new DateTime(delayedInputDate.Year, 6, 30);
else
    resultDate = new DateTime(delayedInputDate.Year, 12, 31);
```

Comment: While this may or may not be correct from a functional perspective (I haven't checked), I would strongly advise **against** such a solution. Code that clearly communicates intent (spec, business rules) should be preferred over "clever" algorithms.

Comment: @nodots In general I agree with you. But as OP knows a solution, and still asks for a better one, maybe he asks for an interesting one.

Comment: @nodots And `Code that clearly communicates intent` is highly subjective. In the question, poster is trying to explain the problem. It takes lots of sentences. If you shift 3 months, then everything gets easy. My intent was not to give a solution, but to give a new point of view.